# My application cannot update Access database after deployment to "C:\Program Files\..."

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, datagridview, ms-access-2010, visual-studio-2013

I have deployed my application to be ready for use by another user (another computer), but when I try to add the data to the database I get the error

> Operation must use an updatable query

The error is like this (This is when I already deployed my program and run under application, not under Visual Studio):

[image]

But it works perfectly under visual studio, the image like this (note that, the error on the image above appear once I click the submit button, it supposed to stored in the database, and display it on the datagridview as like image below):

[image]

And also I got another problem, the delete function is not running, the error on the add and delete appear once I deployed my program, but I will post that on another thread.

How do I solve this?

Comment: What Windows permissions does your application's user have on the db file and on the folder where it is located?

Comment: How do i check on that sir?

Comment: In Windows Explorer, right-click the db file and choose Properties.  Then examine the Security tab of the properties dialog.  Do the same for the folder which contains the db file.  The user must be able to create or at least update a lock file in that folder in order to open the db in read-write mode.  Without the lock file capability, she can only open the db read-only.

Comment: the folder contains database and the program inside it are read-only, but when i unchecked it, the message says it must have permission from administrator, when i click continue, nothing changes.. How do i solve this sir? And is it possible to do with the code before deploying this system? Thank you

Comment: the program works perfectly on the D:Program Files sir, not in the C:Program Files or system file. Why is it like that?

Comment: If you don't have administrator privilege, ask someone who does have that privilege to make the change.  Otherwise, install the db file somewhere the user has read-write permission by default (such as the user's Documents folder), and you may need to revise the application to tell it where to find the db file.

Comment: Recent Windows versions do not allow normal users write permission in `C:\Program Files`.  That is not a good place to store an Access db file which you want the users to modify.

Comment: So, in a safe way, i must install the program under D:Program Files? not in the system folder? because of that reason that you said that is not a good place to store an access db file on the system which i want the users to be able to modify it

Comment: and sir, if i could ask, how do i change the path location of the installation setup to be under D:Program Files? not under C:Program Files in VS?

Comment: If the user(s) have read-write privilege on `D:\Program Files`, that can work.  The installation setup is a .Net issue and I can't help with that.  If you can't find what you need by searching previous questions, you may need to ask a new question.

Comment: alright.. once again, thank you

Answer (score 5):

When a Visual Studio application is under development it resides in a folder to which the developer has read/write access. This is obviously necessary since the developer needs to be able to edit the source code files. If you place a database file "in with the code" then the application can update the database file because it is in a "writable" location.

However, if on deployment the database file stays "with the code" and the installer puts the files (i.e., the executable file and the database file) into `%ProgramFiles%` on the target machine (for example, `C:\Program Files\MyApplication`) then the average user will **not** have write access to that location. Files in `%ProgramFiles%` are normally restricted to read-only to protect the system from malware.

Some people will try and configure the installer to grant write access to normal users for some file(s) or folder(s) under `%ProgramFiles%` but that is a **Bad Idea™**. The installer should really copy the database file to a location that is normally read/write for the intended user(s): either `%USERPROFILE%` (for a specific user), or `%PUBLIC%` (for all users).

Comment: Thanks for your explanation sir, but i am not quite understand what should i do next sir @Gord Thompson?

Comment: @Kaoru I see you have opened a new question, which is good. We will continue over there.

Comment: If I could upvote this 50 more times I would. I spent two hours trying to figure out why I couldn't save data to the DB, but I got no errors connecting. Thanks Gord!