# Change default location of installation properties

Tags: c#, visual-studio, setup-project

How do I change the default location on deployment visual studio? I already deployed my application using visual studio, but the default location is on `C:Program Files`. How do I make it to `D:Program Files` for the default location?

This image belong to default location `C:Program Files`:

[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to move the Visual Studio project, or change the deployment location?

Comment: change the deployment location sir, not move the visual studio project

Comment: You should probably have mentioned if you are using a setup project.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for is a bad idea to do in the setup project. Your project should be deploying to the "Program Files" special folder on the user's machine.

If you need it to go to D:\Program Files, then that special folder should be changed on the user's machine, not in your setup project. What if the user has his program files folder on the E: drive?

Comment: Please see the earlier question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20427927/2144390). The OP is including an Access database file that is currently getting copied into `%ProgramFiles%` and hence cannot be updated because the user does not have write access to files in that location. I suggested having the installer copy the database file to either `%USERPROFILE%` or `%PUBLIC%`. I certainly agree that the executable stuff should remain in `%ProgramFiles%`. Perhaps you could edit your answer to give the OP a hint as to how they might achieve that.

Comment: @GordThompson: it sounds like you already gave the OP the answer, and that he's ignoring you

Comment: So, do you mean that i must have a copy of the database in another location besides in the system file sir @GordThompson?

I wanted to do that because i had a problem not being able to modify the database under system file (C:Program Files) sir @JohnSaunders

Answer (score 0):

You can either modify the enviroment variable for the default installation path on the target machine or just replace `[ProgramFilesFolder]` of the DefaultLocation property by your path (`D:\Program Files`).

But keep in mind: If you change the enviroment variable, it applies to ALL applications that will be installed on that machine. If you change the DefaultLocation property it might lead to wrong behavior, as the drives can have different names on each machine.