# VB.NET and Access readonly after copying

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I wrote a program in vb.net to copy files to a location and one happens to be an access DB.
The file isn't readonly but the database is. I don't know how to do an ALTER statement properly in oledb to change to read_write and haven't found anything that really helps. I did see a related post, but they only try to change the readonly file access and it's not in the file, it's a database setting, it seems, since I did check all the flags and settings on the file. How do I alter it?

UPDATE:

I did add `Mode=ReadWrite`:

`"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\CORA.accdb;Mode='ReadWrite`
This does, however, require me to run the program as admin which is an issue. I need to be able to run with `ReadWrite` access and as a regular user.

Is there a way to edit the properties using Access? Does anyone have any advice?

UPDATE:

Gord, you were correct. One of the directories had the wrong permissions. I changed to a directory without permissions set on it and it works. Thanks.

Comment: Do regular users have write access to the *folder* in which the database file resides?

Comment: You could be onto something, I placed it in program files (x86) which seems to have locked permissions by default.

Comment: See a similar answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20430483/2144390).